# What is the access of properties on an object called in the syntax?

Tags: javascript, naming

Let's say we have an object

```
var object = {
    propertyOne: {
        propertyTwo: 'Value'
    }
}
```

What would the property names like these (`propertyOne.propertyTwo`) be called?

The word would also have to include `object.propertyOne`.

It could also be the name for the final property `propertyTwo`.

To explain if I had a object and I would want to access a certain property of it or the object's properties property and I would have a string like `'propertyOne.propertyTwo'` or `'propertyOne'` what would I name that string?

To give context, I have an angular $scope and there are strings of property names that angular parses to access that scope object. That's the string that I am asking about.

The word would have to be [invariable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_invariant_nouns).

Comment: I would refer to those as *nested* properties.

Comment: Nested properties, sub-properties

Comment: Or nested objects. They're all just jargon terms.Strictly it's an object property whose value is a reference to another object.

Comment: Correct answers I will have to rephrase the question, I am looking for a generic word for all the properties. For example if it were just propertyOne.

Comment: Literally "properties" is the word I would use for that, whereas floating variables not attached to something I would refer to as simply "variables". For functions attached to an object I would call those "methods" and ones not attached to anything "functions".

Comment: Correct, that leads me to think of property names chained as by the definition of property "an attribute common to all members of a class", the property itself could not be a name. So what are multiple or singular property names?

Comment: Hmm, you've lost me now.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that properties are the actual values, thus using just properties is invalid. property names > properties. And the second thing was that the word would have to be invariable. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_invariant_nouns

Answer (score 0):

> What would the property access list like this (object.propertyOne.propertyTwo) be called? 'propertyOne.propertyTwo' in particular?

`propertyOne.propertyTwo` will termed as a property of `object`.

Again

```
propertyTwo will be termed as a property of `propertyOne`.
```

In-general we refer them as nested properties to give a hint that there are multiple level of object inside original  json.

Comment: Can the word "property"  be used to refer to a property of the object's properties properties?

Comment: @OlaviSau Yes. You can. More specifically you can refer that as nested property

Comment: see the updated question please, so you think I could just call the example string propertyName, if I would want to include both nested and unnested properties?

Answer (score -2):

To access inner property we should use object.propertyOne.propertyTwo, if you will try propertyOne.propertyTwo then you will get error ReferenceError: Can't find variable: propertyOne

Comment: Nothing about the question asks *how* to do that.